# Add space in enum in Meta Data Response in XML in C#

Tags: c#, xml, .net-core, odata, metadata

I know that C# doesn't supports space in between enum. So after researching I found this example which I tried in a console example and it worked, I am unable to implement it in `Program.cs` of .NET 6.0

Current meta data response:

```xml
<EnumType Name="myEnum">
  <Member Name="First_Option" Value="0" />
</EnumType>
```

Expected result:

```xml
<EnumType Name="myEnum">
    <Member Name="First Option" Value="0" />
</EnumType>
```

I tried this method in console:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;

public enum MyEnum
{
    [Description("First Option")]
    FirstOption
}

public static class EnumExtensions
{
    public static string GetDescription(this Enum value)
    {
        var field = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());
        var attribute = (DescriptionAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(
            field,
            typeof(DescriptionAttribute)
        );

        return attribute == null ? value.ToString() : attribute.Description;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        MyEnum option = MyEnum.SecondOption;

        Console.WriteLine(option.GetDescription());
    }
}
```

Returns First Option

I want to add this to Meta Data in .NET 6.0 `Program.cs`:

```
static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
{
    ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

    builder.EntitySet<Project.Car>("Car");

    builder.EnumType<MyEnum>();

    return MetadataMapper(builder.GetEdmModel());
}

static IEdmModel MetadataMapper(IEdmModel model)
{
    var stringType = EdmCoreModel.Instance.GetString(true);
    var srNumber = new EdmStringConstant(stringType, "Unique Identifier in the API Context.");

    model.SetAnnotationValue(
        ((IEdmEntityType)model.FindType("Project.Car")).FindProperty("srNumber "),
        "",
        "Description",
        srNumber
    );

    return model;
}
```

Comment: You want `[EnumMember( Value = "first option" )]` - not `[Description()]` - furthermore, the `DescriptionAttribute` is effectively replaced by `DisplayAttribute` thesedays (which also replaced `DisplayNameAttribute`)

Comment: Yes the value is needed with out space in Meta Data in XML which is auto generated from Swagger.